# Select Active and Recently Completed "Tasks" from Table

Tags: linq, database-design, entity-framework-4

I have a Tasks table something like;

```
    PK  TaskId
        TaskName
        Notes
        ...
        ...
    FK  StatusId
        DateCompleted
```

What I want to do is get a list if tasks that are active **plus** any tasks completed in the last 7 days.

At the moment I have;

```
var then = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
return _db.Tasks
    .Where(t => (t.StatusId != 1))
    .Union(_db.Tasks
    .Where(t => (t.DateCompleted >= then))
    );
```

Is this the most sensible way to do it? I am creating the DB from scratch so that can change to suit a better method :)

Cheers
Si

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other alternative is:

```
var day = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
return _db.Tasks
    .Where(t => t.StatusId != 1 || t.DateCompleted >= day);
```

This is more concise but can only use a single index (either StatusId or DateCompleted). Your `Union` technique might allow using both indices but has a chance of overlapping.

To improve your solution you can use `Concat()` instead of `Union()` which does not eliminate duplicates, if you're sure there won't be an overlap between two sets. `Concat()` will turn into `UNION ALL` which is faster than `UNION`.

Comment: Thank's to both ssg & Matti. For this application speed won't really be an issue, this is a more elegant solution than mine :) The resulting SQL in LinqPad is a lot less gnarly too!

Answer (score 0):

The database itself seems OK, but couldn't you just use a simple "or" in the query?

```
_db.Tasks.Where(t => t.StatusId != -1 || t.DateCompleted >= then)
```